# How can I determine if my walk of 3 numbered points on a circle was in clockwise order?

Tags: geometry, circles

I have 3 numbered points which lie on a circle. I want to walk them in order from first to third.

How can I determine if my walk was clockwise order or not?

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Comment: In order to answer this question we have to know in which format the three points are given.

Comment: just compute the signed area $\frac12 \sum (x_i y_{i+1} - y_i x_{i+1})$ of the triangle. if it is positive, then your points are ordered counterclockwisely. if it is negative, then your points are ordered clockwisely. This also works for any non-self intersecting polygon.